# Spring boot register an instance as a bean

Tags: spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I am trying to register Datasource instance as a bean in java code(spring-boot project)

Here is what I wrote. (This code is not working.)

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dsMap;


    private Map<String, String> getTestDataSourceInfo () {
        Map<String, String> ds = new HashMap<String, String> ();
        ds.put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://123.456.78.912:3306/test");
        ds.put("username", "testuser");
        ds.put("password", "testuser");
        return ds;
    }

    public DatabaseConfig () {
        this.dsMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        dsMap.put("sampleDs", getTestDataSourceInfo());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadDataSource () {

        logger.info("DS ================================ :: " +  String.valueOf(this.dsMap));
        this.dsMap.forEach((k,v) -> {

            logger.info("value ========================== :: " + String.valueOf(v));
            DataSource aSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName(v.get("driverClassName"))
                    .url(v.get("url"))
                    .username(v.get("username"))
                    .password(v.get("password"))
                    .build();
            // PROBLEM STARTS ..............
            // Add datasource instance with name to context 

            context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(aSource);
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any proper way to register bean with an instance?
I could not find any fine samples for this.

---

FYI, What I have expected in above code is...

- Spring boot application will read above class as a `Configure`
- It will make an Java instance in its constructor
- And it will add the instance as a bean to application context in `loadDatasource` method

However, it is not working. So I am curious about how to add an java instance as a bean to current Spring boot application context.

Comment: Spring boot comes with auto configuration for datasources: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html You don't have to use it, but in any case it can show you how to use it either in standalone (register yourself) or in aut-config

Comment: @pandaadb Thanks for the reference and sorry that I did not make my point clear. The thing I want to know is not how to use embedded datasource bean, it is all about how to register a java instance as a bean to current application context. I also edit the content with the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it could be more easier if I did not do this with `DataSource`.

Since, Spring-boot automatically do configure `dataSource`, I have to disable this settings first.

Here is what I did to achieve the goal

In `@Configuration` Class...

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> dsMap;


    private Map<String, String> getTestDataSourceInfo () {
        Map<String, String> ds = new HashMap<String, String> ();
        ds.put("driverClassName", "${ your driverClassName }");
        ds.put("url", "${ your url }");
        ds.put("username", "${ your user }");
        ds.put("password", "${ your password }");
        return ds;
    }

    public DatabaseConfig () {
        this.dsMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        dsMap.put("sampleDs1", getTestDataSourceInfo());
        dsMap.put("sampleDs2", getTestDataSourceInfo());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadDataSource () {
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)  context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        this.dsMap.forEach((k,v) -> {

            BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(BasicDataSource.class);
            v.forEach((ds_key, ds_val) -> {
                builder.addPropertyValue(ds_key, ds_val);
            });
            BeanDefinition def = builder.getBeanDefinition();
            if(!registry.containsBeanDefinition(k)) registry.registerBeanDefinition(k, def);
        });
    }
}
```

In above class, I could add java instances to spring bean with `BeanDefinitionRegistry` and `BeanDefinitionBuilder`.

If this is just a bean, it would be end here, but what you are trying to add is `DataSource` bean, have to do some extra work.

Since, boot automatically setting `DataSource`, we have to disable that setting to register customized datasource.

In your `@SpringbootApplication` class, add `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`.

Now, you are able to user those bean in other beans via `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`.

Thanks.